# Stop auto play home page slider in Magento 1.9.1

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme, slider

I have used the default home page slider functionalities. the slider is running one by one. Need to stop the automatic slider running. I have checked the js file `skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\lib\jquery.cycle2.min.js` and `skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\lib\jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js` files to stop the transition. But not able to stop the transition.

Comment: before posting the answer edited :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/slideshow.js` and replace code with this:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

    // ==============================================
    // UI Pattern - Slideshow
    // ==============================================

    $j('.slideshow-container .slideshow')
        .cycle({
            slides: '> li',
            pager: '.slideshow-pager',
            pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
            speed: 6000,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            swipe: true,
            prev: '.slideshow-prev',
            next: '.slideshow-next',
            fx: 'scrollHorz'
        }).cycle('pause');
});
```

See `cycle('paus')`, this is telling the slider to not scroll automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or you can just use timeout property.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use the timeout field. Edit the file mentioned by @Aadarsh which is  `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/slideshow.js` or copy this file to your skin folder and edit it as below:

```
$j('.slideshow-container .slideshow')
    .cycle({
        slides: '> li',
        pager: '.slideshow-pager',
        pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
        speed: 600,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        swipe: true,
        prev: '.slideshow-prev',
        next: '.slideshow-next',
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 0
    });
```

Thank you